# How to implement Azure Speech To Text REST API using http request on nativescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest, azure, nativescript

I have an app that should use Azure Speech-to-Text SDK. There's no direct tutorial or any for nativescript. I tried the steps on their [documentation](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwigqPS4kPjeAhUEVbwKHc-jBAkQFjABegQICRAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fazure.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fresources%2Fsamples%2Fspeechtotext-websockets-javascript%2F&usg=AOvVaw2ZghzwM-QDz7h0wcs38lzh) but im not sure if im doing it right.

Here's my code that i'm currently using

```
 var session = bghttp.session("image-upload");
var request = {
    url: "https://southeastasia.stt.speech.microsoft.com/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1?language=en-US&format=simple",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {            
        "Accept": "application/json;text/xml",
        "Content-Type": "audio/wav; codec=audio/pcm; samplerate=16000",
        "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key": "SUBSCRIPTION_KEY"
    },
    description: "{ 'uploading': '" + "recording.mp3" + "' }"
};
var task = session.uploadFile(fs.path.normalize(recordedFile.path), request);
```

and here's the result that i get after uploading. i get "error" status
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've developed this sample code and it works fine

```
import http.client, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '8...c',
} 

def get_access_token():
    try:
        conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com')
        conn.request("POST", "/sts/v1.0/issueToken", None, headers)
        response = conn.getresponse()
        access_token = response.read()
        conn.close()
        return access_token
     except Exception as e:
         print(e)

acc_tok = get_access_token().decode("utf-8")

from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService
account_name = 'samplewavstorage'
account_key = '4...A=='
service = BlockBlobService(account_name, account_key)

spech = service.get_blob_to_bytes('speechsamplewav','jp1mono.wav')

recorequestheader = {
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + acc_tok,
}

conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection('westus.stt.speech.microsoft.com')
conn.request("POST", "/speech/recognition/conversation/cognitiveservices/v1? 
language=ja-JP&format=simple", spech.content, recorequestheader)
response = conn.getresponse()
res = response.read()
conn.close()
print(res.decode(encoding='UTF-8'))
```